# Rotating point about pivot point in 3d space

Tags: java, vector, 3d, rotation, render

I've made a Java program that displays lines in 3d space projected onto the 2d view, and so far, it's been working pretty well. I tried to make it possible to essentially rotate the 'world' about the camera's position about any axis, but now I'm running into some problems.

```
public void rotate(){
    float ax = main.angleX; //main = camera
    float ay = main.angleY;
    float az = main.angleZ;
    for(Line3d line : lines){ //all lines in the world
        Vector3d start = Vector3d.Vector3dPMinus(line.start, main.getPoint()); //vetor value of starting point of line - camera's position
        Vector3d end = Vector3d.Vector3dPMinus(line.end, main.getPoint());
        start.rotate(ax, ay, az);
        end.rotate(ax, ay, az); //rotate each vector
        line.start = Point3d.pointFromVector3d(start).add(main.getPoint());
        line.end = Point3d.pointFromVector3d(end).add(main.getPoint()); //vectors back into points
    }
}
```

Rotation function:

```
public Vector3d rotate(float ax, float ay, float az){
    Math.toRadians(ax *= 90);
    Math.toRadians(ay *= 90);
    Math.toRadians(az *= 90);
    y = (float) (y * Math.cos(ax) - z * Math.sin(ax));
    z = (float) (y * Math.sin(ax) + z * Math.cos(ax));
    x = (float) (x * Math.cos(ay) + z * Math.sin(ay));
    z = (float) (z * Math.cos(ay) - x * Math.sin(ay));
    x = (float) (x * Math.cos(az) - y * Math.sin(az));
    y = (float) (x * Math.sin(az) + y * Math.cos(az));
    return this;
}
```

I've set it rotate about the x axis 3 times per second, and it displays exactly what I want it to before it starts rotating, but once it starts rotating, there's just some unidentifiable mess of usually just one horizontal line.

Is the method I used for rotating not right? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: You say you want to rotate the world around *any* axis, but your code seems to be trying to perform a rotation around an axis specific to the camera.  Perhaps around the camera view direction?  If that's the case, why not spin the camera instead?

Answer (score 0):

A Rotation of a 3d vector around the 3 axis is not that trivial as one might think. The thing you are probably trying to do is rotating with so called [Euler Angles](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerAngles.html). You should be familiar with [matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)) to work with 3d space. I checked your rotations and they should work fine. BUT you should keep the following in mind: When you are rotating around an angle. The following rotations are affected by the previous rotation. You are rotating the rotation axis too. 
To avoid this behaivour one ugly possibility is to rotate around a free axis. And when you are rotating around the x axis first. You rotate the y axis in reverse and rotate then your point around this y'. When you are rotating around z you need to rotate z axis with your reversed x and y rotation and then rotate around this z'. When you are doing this, you can always rotate around your world coordinatesystem. You should really use some math Library to accomplish this. It makes your life much easier. When you want to code it yourself. You need a proper matrice class with multiplication of matrices and vectors and some inversion method.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach appears to take a reasonable general form.  It looks like you are rotating the line endpoints relative to the current camera position, which is correct, and the three specific rotations you are performing *could* also be correct (but see below).

However, the three `Math.toRadians()` calls cannot be doing anything useful, because you ignore their results.  Moreover, the expression `ax *= 90` and its mates look awfully suspicious: are `ax`, `ay`, and `az` really expressed as fractions of a quarter-circle?  That seems doubtful, and if it were the case then you would want to multiply by `Math.PI/2` and skip `toRadians()`.  On the other hand, if they are expressed in degrees then the following version of `rotate()` is correct for **one** reasonable definition of `ax`, `ay`, and `az`, and **some** possible `Vector3D` implementations:

```
public Vector3d rotate(double ax, double ay, double az){
    ax = Math.toRadians(ax);
    ay = Math.toRadians(ay);
    az = Math.toRadians(az);
    y = (float) ( y * Math.cos(ax) - z * Math.sin(ax));
    z = (float) ( y * Math.sin(ax) + z * Math.cos(ax));
    x = (float) ( x * Math.cos(ay) + z * Math.sin(ay));
    z = (float) (-x * Math.sin(ay) + z * Math.cos(ay));
    x = (float) ( x * Math.cos(az) - y * Math.sin(az));
    y = (float) ( x * Math.sin(az) + y * Math.cos(az));
    return this;
}
```

Overall, though, I am also a bit dubious of the correctness of the `ax`, `ay`, and `az` for this purpose.  In particular, be aware that you cannot just accumulate separate x, y, and z rotation increments independently, as the resulting aggregate rotation depends greatly on the order in which the incremental rotations are performed.  Moreover, even if `ax`, `ay`, and `az` correctly describe the orientation of the camera, it is unlikely that applying the same rotation to the world is what you actually want to do.

DESPITE ALL THE FOREGOING, though, I don't see any reason why your code would *distort* the model as you describe it doing.  I don't think it will apply the rotation you want (even with my suggested fix), but the reason for the distortion is likely somewhere else.

Comment: I realize the ax*=90 issue, and ax, ay, and az are in fact fractions of a quarter circle. I changed the Math.toRadians to just doing it manually, but there's a slight problem. It more or less works for rotating along the z axis, albeit getting smaller/further away(idk which), but for the x axis, it doesn't display properly, and for y, it just disappears completely.